# why not work multiple Thumbs gallery with swipre on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with three slides (pageSwiper).
The scenario is that when each of these slides is clicked, a modal will open and there will be a "Thumbs gallery" inside each modal (mySwiper2 , mySwiper).
But due to the existence of several "Thumbs gallery", these (swiper-button-next, swiper-button-prev) items do not work.
If you have a suggestion for solving this problem, thank you for letting me know.
Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

```js
var swiperpage = new Swiper(".pageSwiper", {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      effect: "fade",
      navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
      },
});

 var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    slidesPerView: 4,
    freeMode: true,
    watchSlidesProgress: true,
});
var swiper2 = new Swiper(".mySwiper2", {
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    thumbs: {
        swiper: swiper,
    },
});
```

```css
.page--slider{
    padding: 0 56px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    padding: 2rem;
}
.pageSwiper .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.pageSwiper .swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.pageSwiper .swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.pageSwiper .swiper-button-next,
.pageSwiper .swiper-button-prev{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;
}
.pageSwiper .swiper-button-next:after, 
.pageSwiper .swiper-button-prev:after {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    font-weight: bolder !important;
}

.pageSwiper .swiper-pagination-bullet {
    width: 13px !important;
    height: 13px !important;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5) !important;
}

.pageSwiper .swiper-pagination-bullet:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7) !important;
}
.pageSwiper .swiper-pagination-bullet-active{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.9) !important;
}


/* The Modal */
.modal {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1100; 
    padding-top: 100px; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.modal-content {
    -webkit-animation: slide-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: slide-bottom 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    width: 50%;
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 90%;
    padding:  0 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: var(--cw);
    border-radius:8px;
    padding: 13px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.modal-content-slider{
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.modal-content-buttons{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15%;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.modal-content-close{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    position: relative;
}

.close {
    color: var(--cw);
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 90%);
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 100;    
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
    margin: auto 0;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.close:hover{
    opacity: .5;
}

/* swiper Modal */
.modal .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal .swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.modal .swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.modal .swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.modal .swiper-slide {
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.modal .mySwiper2 {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
}

.modal .mySwiper {
    height: 20%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.modal .mySwiper .swiper-slide {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.modal .mySwiper .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal .swiper-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="page--slider">  
     <div class="swiper pageSwiper">
           <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                 <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div>
                          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg" class="myBtn_multi"/>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                       <div>
                          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-12.jpg" class="myBtn_multi"/>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide">
                       <div>
                          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" class="myBtn_multi"/>
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
       </div>
     </div>
</div>


<!-- The Modals -->
<div>
<div class="modal modal_multi">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-content-slider">
               <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
                     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="swiper-slide">
                                 <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
                           </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                 <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                            </div>                            
                            </div>
              <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              </div>
              <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
                   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
                        </div>
                         <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                         </div>                                
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
          <div class="modal-content-buttons">
                <div class="modal-content-close">
                     <span class="close close_multi">&times;</span>
                </div>
          </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal modal_multi">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-content-slider">
               <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
                     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="swiper-slide">
                                 <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
                           </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                 <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                            </div>                            
                            </div>
              <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              </div>
              <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
                   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
                        </div>
                         <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                         </div>                                
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
          <div class="modal-content-buttons">
                <div class="modal-content-close">
                     <span class="close close_multi">&times;</span>
                </div>
          </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal modal_multi">
     <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-content-slider">
               <div style="--swiper-navigation-color: #fff; --swiper-pagination-color: #fff" class="swiper mySwiper2">
                     <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                          <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="swiper-slide">
                                 <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
                           </div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                 <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                            </div>                            
                            </div>
              <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
              <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
              </div>
              <div thumbsSlider="" class="swiper mySwiper">
                   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
                        </div>
                         <div class="swiper-slide">
                              <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                         </div>                                
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
          <div class="modal-content-buttons">
                <div class="modal-content-close">
                     <span class="close close_multi">&times;</span>
                </div>
          </div>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to this question:
https://raddy.co.uk/blog/multiple-instances-of-swiperjs-on-the-same-page-with-the-same-settings/

> Create a few sliders with the same class name of “swiper-container” ( you can add as many as you want). Your code should look similar to mine:

HTML:

```html
<div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container">
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
   <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

> Now we need to select the class name "swiper-container", loop through each available element (example: div, section) on the page and then add a new unique class name to each to initialize unique Swipers.

```js
const myCustomSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-container');
for( i=0; i< myCustomSlider.length; i++ ) {
  myCustomSlider[i].classList.add('swiper-container-' + i);
  var slider = new Swiper('.swiper-container-' + i, {
  /* Options */
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's a little like using a hammer on a fly, but sure, it works, another approach is to create the dom elements on the fly and put those into Swiper - it also supports `HTMLElement` - "String with CSS selector or HTML element of the element that will work like "prev" button after click on it"